# Dividing n balls into n buckets so 2 are empty.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

We know that the balls and buckets are distinguishable, and n>2. I was searching the site for some clues but didn't really find any of them helpful. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please make your question clear. Are the labels for the balls or buckets?

Comment: Oh i missed it, for both of them.

Comment: Any thoughts about what? You haven't clearly expressed a question. Please edit your question so that it is clear what you are asking. Also, do you mean *exactly* two buckets are empty, or *at least* two buckets are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume the question is, how many ways are there to distribute $n$ distnguishable balls among $n$ distinguishable buckets in such a way as to leave exactly two buckets empty.

First, choose the two buckets to be empty --- $n\choose2$ ways to do this.

Now you could have $3$ balls in one bucket, one ball in every other bucket. $n-2$ ways to choose the 3-ball bucket, $n\choose3$ ways to choose the balls to go in it, $(n-3)!$ ways to distribute the other balls.

Or, you could have $2$ balls in each of two buckets, one ball in each other bucket. $n-2\choose2$ ways to choose the two buckets, $n\choose4$ ways to choose the four balls that will go into those two buckets, $4\choose2$ ways to distribute the four balls to the two buckets, $(n-4)!$ ways to dispose of the other balls.

Can you combine all these numbers to get the answer?

Comment: I'm not really sure, would you mind helping me?

Comment: Yes, I would. First of all, you have to edit your question in line with the suggestions already made. Second, you have to spend more than 5 minutes thinking about what I've written in my answer. Then, you have to make some effort to put the numbers together, and let us know what you have achieved, and where you have become stuck, and what *exactly* you are unsure of.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do my best and let you know. You're helpful indeed :)

Comment: So here it is. And yes, you understood my question correctly. (n 2) * [ (n-2)*(n 3)*(n-3)!+({n-2} 2)*(n 4)*(n 2)*(n-4)!]

Comment: Empty space stands for binomial coefficient

Comment: Your last $n\choose 2$ (put n\choose2 inside dollar signs to get that) should be $4\choose2$; other than that, looks good.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot!

Comment: The way to thank people here is (should you choose to do so) to "accept" the answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Politely explained, humbly done.